# Regex Ruby Confusion

Tags: regex, ruby, io

I'm currently building an arbitrary ruby program but my name validation through ruby (not using rails yet) to validate is consistently not working because when I enter pure numbers it runs fine when it shouldn't.

```
def user_input
  puts 'What is your name?'
  user_name = gets.chomp
  name_pattern = Regexp.new('/\A[^0-9`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]+\z/')
  while user_name =~ name_pattern
    puts 'please enter a real name'
    user_name = gets.chomp
  end
  user_name
end

def main
  user_name = user_input
  puts "\n"
  puts user_name.to_s
end
```

In addition I've tried the regex /[a-z]+/ just to check if it is my regex and it appears that is not as well since when I type 33 with regex /[a-z]+/ it also works just fine? What am I doing wrong here lol.

Comment: You are requiring a `/` before start of string, so this is a pattern that never matches any string. Use ``name_pattern = /\A[^0-9`!@#$%^&*+_=]+\z/``

Comment: *it runs fine when it shouldn't* -- This is not a great way to describe a problem. What does "it runs fine" mean?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your regex contains a forward slash at the beginning and end.

This code defines a regex for "one or more lower-case letters":

```
name_pattern = /[a-z]+/
# OR
name_pattern = Regex.new('[a-z]+')
```

This code defines a regex for "the *whole string* can only consist of one-or-more lower-case characters":

```
name_pattern = /\A[a-z]+\z/
# OR
name_pattern = Regex.new('\A[a-z]+\z')
```

This code defines a regex for "the *whole string* can only consist of characters that are **not** digits, nor certain symbols":

```
name_pattern = /\A[^0-9`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]\z/
# OR
name_pattern = Regex.new('\A[^0-9`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]\z')
```

---

Your code is confusing the two syntaxes, by adding literal slashes to the start and end of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring a `/` before start of string (`\A`), so your `` /\A[^0-9`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]+\z/ `` ***pattern*** is a pattern that never matches any string.

Use

```rb
name_pattern = /\A[^0-9`!@#$%^&*+_=]+\z/
```

Or, if you prefer a `Regexp.new` notation,

```rb
name_pattern = Regexp.new('\A[^0-9`!@#$%^&*+_=]+\z')
```

Also, `$` inside a character class never requires escaping, `[$]` always matches a literal `$` char.

The `^` char inside a character class only needs escaping if it is the first char in the class. Here, it is not the first, so there is no need escaping it.